# Ajax и исходный html код страницы

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, php, форма

Здравствуйте.

Возникла такая проблема.
При помощи ajax данные из формы отправляются в php обработчик в фоновом режиме, затем обработанные возвращаются в браузер - без перезагрузки. 
В принципе всё работает так, как нужно, но есть одно НО - если открыть исходный html код странички, там не видны изменения, которые делает php обработчик. Изменения в html появляются только тогда, когда всю страницу перезагрузить полностью.

Смотрел на многих сайтах, где комментарии отсылаются в фоновом режиме - там все изменения моментально видны в html коде, у меня же не видны. В чём может быть дело, в какую сторону следует копать? Чувствую, что что-то делаю неправильно, и это не даёт мне покоя, хотя если не заморачиваться - всё вроде как работает.

P.S. Если в php обработчике использовать php функцию header, изменения сразу видны в html коде страницы, но тогда обновляется весь тот div, где выводится весь результат, хотелось бы этого избежать.

Answer (score 1):

Если открыть исходный код страницы, никаких изменений там и не должно и не может быть. Откройте консоль отладки/разработчика (f12 обычно) и смотрите в ней структуру документа, все изменения там будут отображаться (не забудьте посмотреть и в #shadow-root).